# Alamofire custom cookie store for multiple Managers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, http, alamofire

Trying to wrap my head around how to handle multiple `Manager's` in Alamofire. I need each Manager to contain it's own cookie storage. i,e: 10 Manager's running at once should have their own set of cookies. Im also using proxies for some and or all requests. Therefor im using **`NSURLSessionConfiguration`**, but only have the option of using **`defaultConfiguration`** which defeats the purpose, if all managers are internally using the default? Hope I explained this correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by utilizing `URLSessionConfiguration`'s `httpCookieStorage` setting cookie storage with `HTTPCookieStorage.sharedCookieStorage(forGroupContainerIdentifier:)`. Giving each one of my configs a different identifier.

Comment: How were you able to keep those cookies persistent? I tried this method and when I exited the app and came back, all the cookies were gone

Answer (score 0):

When you do a URLSessiononfiguration.default, each time a different object is returned with default configurations. You can easily check the same with the === operator for different invokations of URLSessiononfiguration.default. So you can easily make your changes for different managers. Let me know if this helps